# The same data is displayed differently in angular9.why?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, angular9, zonejs

In the following example, the

- first expression  `{{ bar }}` is never updated, but the
- second expression `{{ "" + bar }}` is updated:

e.g.

```
two
1588950994873
```

Why is this the case?

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    What is different and why?
    <br />
    {{ bar }} <br />
    {{ "" + bar }} <br />
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  value: string = "default";

  bar: any = d => {
    this.value = d;
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bar.valueOf = () => this.value;
    this.bar("one");
    setInterval(() => this.bar(Date.now() + ""), 1000);
    this.bar("two");
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8mrhzq)

Comment: Just a theory (that brings no light to this behavior): angular handles different a simple expression when it just has to dereference a variable and when it has to calculate the value it's gonna show inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why is that angular change detection works by comparing the instance of an expression:

- `{{ bar }}`: the instance `bar` never changes - you assign a function to this class member and you never reassign it - so every change detection cycle will see that `bar` is still the same instance and does not update it (i.e. since the instance is the same, we don't even ask for the value)
- `{{ "" + bar }}`: in every change detection cycle the expression `"" + bar` will be evaluated. When this string concatenation is evaluated, we must get the **value** of `bar` which will be updated by your timer. So the result of the string concatenation will always be a new string-instance and thus the change detection will update the view.

Comment: why {{bar}} is 'two' , not  'one' or 'default'?

Comment: the view is not updated before `ngOnInit` is done - so the last assignment "wins". Check the [life-cycle docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)